# Problem with changing string to date with time

Tags: javascript, chart.js, fetch

Date format looks like that: 2020-07-11 23:11:52

I am taking data from csv file using fetch and splitting it into single data

**How to change this string (date) into date with time to plot on the chart**

```
    async function getData(){

        const response =await fetch('data.csv');
        const data = await response.text();
        const table = data.split('\n').slice(1);
        table.forEach(row =>{
            const columns = row.split(',');
            const date = columns[0];
         //   const dayshours = date.split(' ');
         //   const days = dayshours[0];
            xlabels.push(date);
            const temp = columns[1];
            ytemps.push(temp);
            console.log(date, temp);

        });


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the numbers into a string in the ISO standard, which looks like `'2020-08-10T22:36:25.772'`

So in your case it would look like `'2020-07-11T23:11:52.000'`. Note that it looks pretty much identical to what you've already got, except the `T` between the date and the time of day, and append `.000` to the end to set the milliseconds component to zero.

Then take your string and use `new Date('2020-07-11T23:11:52.000')`

[image]

Comment: Glad to help! If this solves your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer - I'd appreciate it a lot!